# Analytic expression for the coefficient of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

Does there exist some method for finding an analytic expression for the coefficient of $z_1^kz_2^kz_3^k$ in:

$$[(1+z_1)(1+z_2)(1+z_3)(1+z_1z_2)(1+z_1z_3)(1+z_2z_3)(1+z_1z_2z_3)]^{k}$$

or is it hopeless?

I can't think of any other method than trying to expand each factor.

Background: the above polynomial is the generating function for a system of linear equations in binary values (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4413256/573047)).

For the simplest case of the coefficient of $z_1^kz_2^k$ in $[(1+z_1)(1+z_2)(1+z_1z_2)]^k$ I found the formula $\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^3$ at [OEIS A000172](https://oeis.org/A000172).

Comment: Taylor coefficient doesn't help?

Comment: $z_1=x,z_2=x^{12k},z_3=x^{(12k)^2}$ you must find the coeff of $x^{k+k\times 12k+k\times (12k)^2}$

Comment: Note that if you can solve it without the last factor, then you can solve it with the last factor as well. The former starts as {4, 84, 2353, 74644, 2570504, 93417141, 3526418676, 136938227092} if my Mathematica is correct.

Comment: The OEIS Superseeker has no suggestions whatsoever, which is fairly discouraging.

Comment: 5, 125, 4217, 163373, 6873505, 305304605, 14090295602, 669067354925, 32476460956025, 1604222480193625.  Probably the asymptotic behaviour can be found.

Comment: 5, 125, 4217, 163373, 6873505, 305304605, 14090295602, 669067354925, 32476460956025, 1604222480193625, 80380036959149680,  4075387263236663069
Special code could quickly find many more terms, perhaps more than 100.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, the obvious Sage two-liner gets 24 terms (25 including $k=0$) in two minutes, but memory usage starts to become a problem. Per's approach would squeeze out a few more terms. Sequence continues 208700059508979095231, 10779043561142979028542, 560841942189830834273092, 29369550998772449215630125, 1546739794102935909806815249, 81869695539756400950043474673, 4352934931813081431729948218755, 232378908415834696591512040624873, 12450814046356118070132295043450105, 669328869650501920320002045039206532, 36090724465969619378056260542868266088, 1951440451620951424228174912475314443293.

Comment: With Per's approach, 49 or 50 terms in SageCell: [online demo](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjjEKwzAMRfdA7qDRckzAQ5fQ9AyhYzbZ2EEksYvjDqX07nXjoQI9ePCF_tRfSRllbzDCFLdXiDvTduewiHnGtsmjbhsfE6zAARKFxQmtLhqHtoEyWY5Cd4Sy0Jy0J0lWM7K6lYT14pE4ZLGq47kLw_VfUUaZexud92zZlcSbBlamrB34g_DrwP8Oa6cR8QtBqTVY&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maple is much slower than SageCell for this, but of course custom code is unbeatable. I put together a C program using gmp and it went up to 128 terms in 40 seconds and 200 terms in 6 minutes. The space requirement is k^3 big integers.  Indefinitely many terms could be found in little space by Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: There is also a sum of $O(k^4)$ terms which are products of 7 binomial coefficients $\binom{k}{x}$ for various $x$. That might be fastest of all but I won't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was coming to the same conclusion that Brendan McKay posted in the comments at about the same time: the efficient way to calculate this is the direct approach $$\sum_{r,s,t,u} \binom{k}{r} \binom{k}{s} \binom{k}{t} \binom{k}{u} \binom{k}{k-r-s-u} \binom{k}{k-r-t-u} \binom{k}{k-s-t-u}$$ where the sum is over the support implicit in the binomial coefficients. (The way I conceptualise this sum is that if you expand $[(1+z_1z_2)(1+z_1z_3)(1+z_2z_3)]^k$ first as $\sum_{r,s,t} \binom{k}{r} \binom{k}{s} \binom{k}{t} (z_1 z_2)^r (z_1 z_3)^s (z_2 z_3)^t$ then you must take individual terms $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ from the $(1+z_i)^k$ to balance them before you consider $(1+z_1 z_2 z_3)^k$.)

I've used the first 300 terms to do a brute-force search for a D-finite recurrence without finding one, so if there is a recurrence then either it's non-linear, it has non-polynomial coefficients, or it's enormous.

Comment: I also looked for a recurrence using 250 terms but no luck.

Comment: Actually, there is a further space-time tradeoff: by pushing in e.g. the sum over $t$ a precalculation in $O(k^3)$ bigint multiplications of a table of $O(k^2)$ values allows the main calculation to be reduced to $O(k^3)$ bigint multiplications.

Comment: I just multiplied the polynomials keeping only the terms needed.  The $O(k^4)$ steps needed for particular $k=n$ gives all the answers for $k\le n$, so it isn't slower than $O(k^3)$ for each $k$ except by a constant. 
The method of summing over roots of unity modulo primes needs $O(k)$ small integers space and $O(k^4/\log k)$ operations (for one $k$). It has the advantage that all the operations are with small integers except for one application of CRT at the end, so it is hard to predict if it will be faster or slower.